# plotting already saved handle in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a cell array `h` with handles, which contains a line object:

Line with properties:

```
          Color: [0 0 0]
      LineStyle: '-'
      LineWidth: 0.5000
         Marker: 'none'
     MarkerSize: 6
MarkerFaceColor: 'none'
          XData: [1.9023e+06 1.9023e+06]
          YData: [1.4689e+07 1.4689e+07]
          ZData: [1×0 double]
```

When I create a new figure, how do I display `h{1}` with all its properties? This is not working since plot does not retain color and other properties:

```
figure;
plot(h{1].XData,h{1].YData);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`copyobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/copyobj.html) to copy over the graphics element to a new figure:

```
figure;
h = plot(randn(100,1),'ro');
figure;
copyobj(h,gca);
```